# How can I return an image from a custom REST API endpoint?

Tags: rest-api

I'm brand new to Wordpress development; Trying to return an image from a custom endpoint, but it seems to want to serialize everything to JSON.

I did manage to get it to work using `echo`. Is that a hack?

I also tried using `WP_HTTP_Response`, but that didn't seem to work.

My code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;

function prefix_generate_cover_photo($data) {
    $image = Image::make(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'image.png')->response();
    $response = new WP_REST_Response($image, 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'image/png'
    ));
    return $response;
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'prefix/v1', '/photo', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'prefix_generate_cover_photo',
    ));
});
```

This works but I'm not sure if it's good practice:

```
function prefix_generate_cover_photo($data) {
    echo Image::make(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'image.png')->response();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/70008574/2342137

> By default, all REST responses are passed through json_encode() to return a JSON string. However, the REST server provides the WP hook [rest_pre_serve_request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_pre_serve_request/) that we can use to return binary data instead.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` in the rest-api and not valid! You should using `return` to make output to Rest API.

For example:

```
function prefix_generate_cover_photo( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    // Get method params
    $params = $request->get_params();

    // Data
    $data = array(
        'url'   => 'The image url',
        'title' => 'The image title',
    );

    // Create the response object
    $response = new WP_REST_Response( array( 'image' => $data ) );

    // Add a custom header (Optional)
    //$response->header( 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache' );

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but returning a url to the image won't work in my case, I need to return the image itself as the response. Is there a way to do that with the REST API? Or is there another recommended way of doing this in wordpress?